# Applications and games opening on the wrong monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, games, monitor

As the title states whenever I open any application or particularly steam game, it will open on the wrong monitor. My secondary display is on the left and the main monitor has been set to main in the display settings. I have also tried using CompizConfig but unfortunately that has not worked either, does anyone have any ideas?
Edit: It appears that this issue occurs if I move my secondary monitor to the left of my main monitor in display settings, I would keep it as the default but I have no room on my right unfortuantely

Sorry, as you can tell im a noob, lesson learned for next time. I'm using Ubuntu desktop 20.04

Comment: Not sure in Ubuntu.  I am a Kubuntu guy. BUT usually there are settings for each application that can force it to be on one monitor.  Once setup it will open in the right place every time.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]